# Unable to echo JQuery $.post method from PHP

Tags: php, jquery

When validating a form, if it fails I want to send the data back to the original form so that users may try again. My current code for this is

```
<body>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<?php
...validation stuff that works....
else{
$page = "/submit.php";
$message = "Your submissions attempt failed, please try again.";
$jquery = "$.post($page, { title: $title, artist: $artist, links: $link, source: $source,tags: $tags }, function(result) {
alert($message);";
echo $jquery;
}
```

but all it does is write the jquery statement to the webpage. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Consider posting to the page that renders this form in the first place.  Then, you can handle any validation and activity before redirecting somewhere else.

Comment: Use a php header redirect with GET vars or Session

Comment: You need to put your JavaScript in `<script></script>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your PHP variables in quotes - otherwise they are variables and keywords.

```
$jquery = "$.post('$page', { title: '$title', artist: '$artist', links: '$link', source: '$source',tags: '$tags' }, function(result) {
alert('$message');";
```

You might want to actually use `json_encode` an object instead and pass that object around.

Comment: That isn't quite the problem here.  His method is fundamentally flawed.  Plus, your method won't encode everything like it needs to be.  `json_encode($_POST)` would be much better.

Comment: I've done that and it doesn't fix the issue. Brad can you expand on your suggestion?